# Only one thread is iterating through the ArrayList in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I have written a code below in which there is list of Employee object in which i have three attributes employeeId,employeeName and salary i am iterating the list using two threads and doing increment of salary by 100. but when this code executes only one thread is doing the job means only one thread i.e "t1" is doing the increment and other thread just not doing anything at all.how can i achieve this thing that all the threads read the list of employee and doing increment the salary attribute.

```
public class MultipleThreadsReadingFromFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "zoheb", 10000);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "anushka", 12000);
        Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "katrina", 15000);
        Employee e4 = new Employee(4, "kareena", 17000);
        Employee e5 = new Employee(5, "priety", 19000);
        Employee e6 = new Employee(6, "rani", 21000);
        Employee e7 = new Employee(7, "sunney", 23000);
        Employee e8 = new Employee(8, "soha", 23000);
        Employee e9 = new Employee(9, "allia", 29000);
        Employee e10 = new Employee(10, "asin", 30000);
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        list.add(e1);
        list.add(e2);
        list.add(e3);
        list.add(e4);
        list.add(e5);
        list.add(e6);
        list.add(e7);
        list.add(e8);
        list.add(e9);
        list.add(e10);
        ListThread run = new ListThread(list);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(run, "t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(run, "t2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("main over");
    }
}
```

ListThread:

```
class ListThread implements Runnable {
    List<Employee> list;
    Iterator<Employee> itr = null;
    Lock lock = null;
    Employee e1=null;

    public ListThread(List<Employee> list) {
        super();
        this.list = list;
        this.itr=list.iterator();
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            //synchronized (itr) {
            try{
            lock.lock();
                if (!itr.hasNext()) {
                    break;
                }
                e1 = itr.next();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " Before change " + e1);
                double salary = e1.getSalary();
                double increment = ((5 / 100) * salary);
                salary = salary + 100;
                // System.out.println(increment);
                e1.setSalary(salary);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + " After change " + e1);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            //}
            }finally{
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Employee:

```
class Employee {
    int employeeId;
    String employeeName;
    double salary;

    public Employee(int employeeId, String employeeName, double salary) {
        super();
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [employeeId=" + employeeId + ", employeeName="
                + employeeName + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: arrayList isn't thread safe, are you asking how to have multiple threads read/write from a list?

Comment: Is there a reason your thread is going to sleep for 5 seconds *before* it releases its lock?

Comment: You should improve the formatting a bit. Barely visible where what starts and ends...

Comment: To make your `ArrayList` thread-safe, use `Collections.synchronizedList()`.

Comment: yes i want that there will be multiple threads reading from the same list which is a list of Employee objects doing some write operation into the object and putting back same Employee object into the list but in this case one one thread is doing the job i have started the two threads i want both should do the job

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the same `Runnable` to both threads, and you create an `Iterator` in the constructor of your `Runnable`, not in the `run()` method, which means both runnables will "compete" for the same list (each element will be processed by only one thread). This might be what you want, however.

As your list is quite small (10 elements), thread `t1` probably has the time to process all elements before thread `t2` fully starts, and then for t2 `itr.hasNext()` returns false and t2 finishes.

EDIT: 
You also keep a lock, so you force thread `t2` to wait for `t1` to finish.
Consider using a [Blocking queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and removing the lock from your `Runnable`, like this (assuming as your example shows that the content of your list is static):

```
public class MultipleThreadsReadingFromFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "zoheb", 10000);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "anushka", 12000);
        Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "katrina", 15000);
        Employee e4 = new Employee(4, "kareena", 17000);
        Employee e5 = new Employee(5, "priety", 19000);
        Employee e6 = new Employee(6, "rani", 21000);
        Employee e7 = new Employee(7, "sunney", 23000);
        Employee e8 = new Employee(8, "soha", 23000);
        Employee e9 = new Employee(9, "allia", 29000);
        Employee e10 = new Employee(10, "asin", 30000);
        BlockingQueue<Employee> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Employee>(10);
        queue.add(e1);
        queue.add(e2);
        queue.add(e3);
        queue.add(e4);
        queue.add(e5);
        queue.add(e6);
        queue.add(e7);
        queue.add(e8);
        queue.add(e9);
        queue.add(e10);
        ListThread run = new ListThread(queue);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(run, "t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(run, "t2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        System.out.println("main over");
    }
}


class ListThread implements Runnable {

    BlockingQueue<Employee> employees;

    public ListThread(BlockingQueue<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Employee e1;
        while ((e1 = this.employees.poll()) != null) {

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " Before change " + e1);
            double salary = e1.getSalary();
            double increment = ((5 / 100) * salary);
            salary = salary + 100;
            // System.out.println(increment);
            e1.setSalary(salary);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " After change " + e1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```